# Cкрипт отправки почты

Tags: javascript, email

Использую вот такой скрипт и кнопку для отправки письма:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function SendMail(){   
    try   
    {   
        // create a session and log on -- username and password in profile    
        var refMsg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message");   
        var refConf = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration");   

        // Setting configuration params   
        with(refConf.Fields)   
        {   
            Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mail.ru";  
            Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2; 
            Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1;  
            Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "***@mail.ru";  
            Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "Тут типо пароль"; 
        }   
        refConf.Fields.Update();   

        with(refMsg)   
        {   
            Configuration = refConf;   
            To       = "кому отправить@ya.ru";   
            From     = "от кого@mail.ru";   
            Subject  = "Тема письма";   
            TextBody = "Текст письма";   
        }
        refMsg.Send();   
    }    
    catch(e)   
    {   
    WScript.Echo("SendMail error !!! : " + e.description);   
    WScript.Quit(1);   
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Отправить" name="rbtest" onClick="SendMail()">
```

Но почему-то и письмо не приходит и даже ошибка никакая не отображается.

P.S. удалил код для прикрепления файла, ибо он не нужен.

Comment: Этот код будет работать только для пользователей windows, не уверен, но скорей всего еще и только в IE

Comment: Советую Вам испоользовать серверные языки - php, perl и т.п.

Comment: Совет: заведите привычку принимать правильные ответы, народ будет активнее отвечать, а то 10% принятых из такого кол-ва вопросов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не JavaScript, это JScript от Мелкософта. Работает с Windows Script Host (WSH; первоначально назывался Windows Scripting Host, был переименован ко второму выпуску) — компонент Microsoft Windows, предназначенный для запуска сценариев на скриптовых языках JScript и VBScript, а также и на других дополнительно устанавливаемых языках (например, Perl). Он предназначен для ASP.NET, а судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам ваш сайт на PHP

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) на сервере. На сайте есть куча примеров. На клиенте достаточно выучить как писать html формы.